# Is Same signs of determinants of $A$ and $B$ $\implies P^tAP =B$

Tags: matrix-congruences

Let $$A = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & b \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$ B= 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{c}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{c}{2}& 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

be two matrices. Find conditions on $b$ and $c$ such $P^tAP = B$ (i.e.$A$ and $B$ are congruent matrices) where $P$ is invertible matrix and $P^t$ = transpose of $P$.

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are congruent then their determinants have same sign.
$|A| = b$ and $|B| = -\frac{c^2}{4}$ then there are two cases arise
Case 1, $c = b = 0$
Case 2, if $c \neq 0$ then $b > 0$
Is same sign of determinants is sufficient condition to make $A$ and $B$ congruent. Provide me alternate solution if you have.

Comment: Have you heard of Sylvester's inertia theorem?

Comment: No. I have not heard.

Comment: [How to use Sylvester's law of inertia](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817906/sylvesters-law-of-inertia), or [How to compute the matrix in Sylvester's inertia law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405538/how-to-compute-the-matrix-s-in-sylvesters-law-of-inertia).